# Is Python django ready Virtual Machine freely available

Tags: python

I was looking at this link

http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/289

Is it free to download or its paid , i cant find the link

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to have a look at the [TurnKey Django Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/django). It's based on Ubuntu Linux and free.

Comment: I have used the Turnkey Django appliance among others and it is great - give it a try.

Comment: does it use mod_wsgl

Comment: By default it uses mod_python, but mod_wsgi can be installed

Answer (score 0):

You would need to ask the developers that question - their website is here: http://www.mcguru.net/pyweb.html - however the VM has not been updated in almost 4 years. That's a long time - I doubt you'd be getting much practical use out of it given its old age.